# Export HTML table to pdf using jspdf font not supporting

Tags: html, pdf, fonts, jspdf, export-to-pdf

I need to export the HTML table to pdf file using jspdf. I tried the below code it's working but it's not supporting my font. here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/5o27wo2q/

```js
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#printableArea')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<div id="printableArea">
   
  
         <table>
    <thead>
     <tr><th>ক্রমিক নং</th>
     <th class="psub">প্রকল্পের ধরন</th>
     <th class="punit">সংখ্যা</th>
                    <th class="punit">
                     দৈর্ঘ্য                     

                    </th>
     <!--<th>দৈর্ঘ্য</th>
     <th>প্রস্থ</th>
     <th>উচ্চতা/গভীরতা </th>
     <th>ক্ষেত্রফল</th>
     <th>অন্যান্য</th>  -->
     <th class="ptotal">বরাদ্দের পরিমাণ</th>
     <th class="ptotal">ব্যয়ের পরিমাণ</th>
     <th class="pyear">অগ্রগতীর হার %</th> 
    
    </tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td class="pdes">
                                      রাস্তা নির্মাণ                                                         </td>
     <td class="psub">255</td>
                    <td class="punit">14166525</td>
     <!--<td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>  
     <td></td> -->
     <td class="ptotal">2357.01</td>
     <td class="ptotal">2357.01</td>
     <td class="pyear">                      100.00

     </td>
     
    </tr>
        <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td class="pdes">
                                      রাস্তা পুনর্নিমাণ                                                         </td>
     <td class="psub">2933</td>
                    <td class="punit">162942815</td>
     <!--<td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>  
     <td></td> -->
     <td class="ptotal">25163.47</td>
     <td class="ptotal">25035.20</td>
     <td class="pyear">                      99.49

     </td>
     
    </tr>
        <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td class="pdes">
                                      রাস্তা মেরামত                                                         </td>
     <td class="psub">1576</td>
                    <td class="punit">87554680</td>
     <!--<td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>  
     <td></td> -->
     <td class="ptotal">14087.86</td>
     <td class="ptotal">14077.93</td>
     <td class="pyear">                      99.93

     </td>
     
    </tr>
                               <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>মোটঃ4764</td>
     <td>মোটঃ264664</td>
     <td>মোটঃ 41608.34</td>
     <td>মোটঃ 41470.14</td>
     
     <td>
      গড়ঃ
      :99.81</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>

   
     </div>
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

or if you want to give any other suggestion without jspdf you can suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 / TTF:
           The 14 standard fonts in PDF are limited to the `ASCII-codepage`. If you want to use `UTF-8` you have to to integrate a custom font, which provides the needed `glyphs. jsPDF supports .ttf-files`. So if you want to have for example chinese text in your pdf, your font has to have the necessary chinese glyphs. So check if your font supports the wanted glyphs or else it will show a blank space instead of the text.
To add the font to jsPDF use our fontconverter in `/fontconverter/fontconverter.html` . The fontconverter will create a js-file with the content of the provided ttf-file as base64 encoded string and additional code for jsPDF. You just have to add this generated js-File to your project. You are then ready to go to use setFont-method in your code and write your UTF-8 encoded text. https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html

You can try something like this (TypeScript):

1. Convert font by font converter (link [here](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html))
2. Then include this font in your code

```js
import { robotoFont } from '../../fonts/roboto.font'; //converted font

pdfDocument = new jsPDF();
pdfDocument.addFileToVFS('Roboto-Regular-normal.ttf', robotoFont);
pdfDocument.addFont('Roboto-Regular-normal.ttf', 'Roboto-Regular', 'normal');
pdfDocument.setFont('Roboto-Regular');
```

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583129/jspdf-with-non-latin-fonts) answer

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583129/jspdf-with-non-latin-fonts):

Answer (score 0):

As of now jsPDF does not support utf-8 characters.

Check this link https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

EDIT:
You can try this as an alternative 
http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/table-export-to-pdf