# How can i convert json in HTML to PDF ? (JsPDf and Angular 11)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, pdf, jspdf

i need to convert html to pdf in Angular 11. I'm using JSPDF library.

Common Html is converted ok:
content.html
`

```
<div #contentToConvert>
<h1>
  H1
</h1>
  <h2> <strong> H2 </strong> </h2>
</div>
```

`

content.ts
`

```
savePdf2() {
 const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  doc.html(this.contentToConvert.nativeElement, {
    callback: (pdf) => {
      pdf.save('sample.pdf');
    },
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  });
}
```

`

This code works, but i need to put some data to html from json, that i get from service. Like this
`

```
<h2> <strong> H2 </strong> {{ main.nameFull.value }} </h2>
```

`
But i cant convert it to pdf, that is what i got [image: PDF]

Comment: Understand, that json  has cyrillic symbols. So, question is how to convert cyrillic in html to pdf?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsPDF with non-latin fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583129/jspdf-with-non-latin-fonts)

Comment: Also see: [how to add and set a font in JsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885556/how-to-add-and-set-a-font-in-jspdf).  You must include a font that supports Cyrillic when you create the PDF.